# How can you identify (or find) the body parts?

Tags: fallout-3

Bear with me, this one might sound a bit ... sick. Let's say you're playing Fallout 3, and you've taken the Bloody Mess perk. Then, you're surrounded by enemies. You go Rambo on them with something like the Gatling Laser or Missile Launcher. Or even use VATS and cut them down with the Xuanlong Assault Rifle.

In the smoky aftermath of doom, how do you identify whose parts are whose for looting? Especially when you're not emptying all of the bodies, and they all have really similar names, like <strike>Megaton Settl</strike> I mean, Raider, um yeah, that's the ticket!

In some cases, when you used VATS and the enemy was far away, how can you even find them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Easiest way? Loot the bodies, then drop the loot. This will allow them to despawn/become non-interactive, allowing you to move on to the next corpse.

Answer (score 7):

If you have patience you can "grab" the body parts with R3 button and put them away making your personal pile of corpse parts :D Then examine the others.
But I think the easiest way is the one suggested by LessPop. ;)